# Help check if I did this inequality correctly

Tags: inequality

Suppose

$0<a<1$, and

$0<b<1$

where $a,b$ are real numbers

Is it correct to say:

$0<a-b<0$ (I just subtracted both inequalities)?

I'm trying to show that the value of $a-b$ will always be less than 1.

Comment: For self-checking: $0<0$ is an invalid statement (whenever you deduce it from something true, you have errored).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0 < a < 1$

$0 < b < 1 \implies -1 < -b < 0$

Adding both inequalities:

$-1 < a-b < 1$

Hence $a-b$ is always less than $1$.

**NOTE:** Always try to add two inequalities instead of subtracting them because when you multiply an inequality with $-1$, the inequality changes.